What does this constructor basic_string<decltype(nullptr)>(char const*) do?
Recently i was reading some assembly codes of aarch64, and i found this strange constructor which seems not defined in the basic_string:
_ZNSt4__n112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC2B6v15004IDnEEPKc

And the demangled name is:
std::__n1::basic_string<char, std::__n1::char_traits<char>, std::__n1::allocator<char> >::basic_string[abi:v15004]<decltype(nullptr)>(char const*)

And this function may do nothing on the given this pointer.
Because in the assembly i found the x8 register is used to store the pointer, and it is constructed by this function, and is destructed before ret.
But later in the caller, this x8 is used in operator=(std::string&, std::string&&), seems this will cause use after free error.
This looks strange, so could anyone tell me what does this function do? And is this function only generated by compiler? (means user cannot write this code)
If i try to use it directly, i will get this error:
context.cpp:11:61: error: cannot call constructor ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string’ directly [-fpermissive]
   11 |     std::basic_string<char>::basic_string<decltype(nullptr)>(name);
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~


It is a template instantion/specializatoin to make constructing a std::string from a nullptr work. e.g std::string str{nullptr} work. nullptr has a type that isn't a char* so it requires special handling

@PepijnKramer Thanks. But i still have a question, constructing string from nullptr will cause a logic_error exception, if the program is compiled with -Oz maybe i'll not see this function occurring here. And i found someone doing reverse says this function has the same function of std::string::c_str(). Which is right?

<decltype(nullptr)> means it was a template instantiaton of std::string for a nullptr type.  Normally std::string exects std::basic_string ('std::string) or std::basic_string<wchar_t> (std::wstring). Both types reuse the (internal) basic_string template. But for nullptr it will becomd std::basic_string<decltype(nullptr)>` (nullptr has an unspecified type that the compiler can choose)

@PepijnKramer OK, this means std::string(nullptr) will be converted by compiler to std::__n1::basic_string<char, std::__n1::char_traits<char>, std::__n1::allocator<char> >::basic_string<decltype(nullptr)>(char const*) ? I hope i do not misunderstand. And thanks for your help :)

@PepijnKramer I checked that just now, it's right. Many thanks!

@PepijnKramer "nullptr has an unspecified type that the compiler can choose" Really? According to https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/lex.nullptr#1, type of nullptr is nullptr_t.

@DanielLangr It is a bit of a self recursive definition  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t  But yes you're right and my mental map has been updated ;)

It is an overload for std::string(nullptr), but note that this constructor is explicitly deleted starting in C++23
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string
basic_string( std::nullptr_t ) = delete;   //   (since C++23)


Thanks. But constructing string from nullptr will cause a logic_error exception, if the program is compiled with -Oz maybe i'll not see this function occurring here. And i found someone doing reverse says this function has the same function of std::string::c_str(). Which is right?
I'm just curious about why there's a <decltype(nullptr)> after the constructors name.

@Cory : Good to know that since this constructor always has been a bit iffy

I think the intention never was for std::string to be constructible from a nullptr.

@ValKmjolnir there's nothing in the standard about it throwing a logic_error, it's undefined behaviour, some implementations might throw an exception but most I've seen just crash with a segfault

@AlanBirtles Maybe lib version is a little bit old or your program is built with -fno-exceptions, otherwise you will get std::logic_error exception

@ValKmjolnir nope, no mention of std::logic_error on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string, your standard library implementation might throw a std::logic_error but that's just your standard library being nice

The <decltype(nullptr_t)> is because it's a member function template overload of the std::string constructor specialized for parameters of type std::nullptr_t. There are several template overload constructors required by the C++ standard, and none of them qualify for a parameter of type std::nullptr_t so it's undefined behaviour. If your compiler accepts it and your library implementation throws an exception, well, nice for you this time. Next time, it might reformat your hard driver.

@AlanBirtles Yes i find there's a comment in the lib sais // NB: Not required, but considered best practice.. You're also right.

@StephenM.Webb Yes it's bad to try to construct string from nullptr. Recently my team was working on detecting these bad cases. So i found this strange mangled name that i've never seen before :)

A history lesson: nullptr didn't exist prior to C++11. NULL was a platform specific macro converting 0 to pointers. C++11 put stricter demands on conversions and required nullptr. Now we had to deal with rule breakers who initialized std::string with null. It never occurred to me that someone might do it. Deleting the constructor in C++23 may be the start of a series of stricter revisions on string init; at least I hope.
